# Is there a shorthand for the Project Root path in PHPStorm?

Tags: php, phpstorm

I'm new to working with PHPStorm and am looking for a helper to make requireing files a bit easier.  I'm in a file that's nested fairly deep in folders, and I need to `require()` a file from just under the Project Root in PHPStorm.

Is there a shorthand in PHPStorm (or plain old PHP) which let's me do something like

```
require('{ROOT}/lib/somefile.php');
```

Instead of having to use relative paths?

```
require('../../../../../../lib/somefile.php');
```

Comment: `define('PROJECT_ROOT', __DIR__);` (or alike) somewhere in index.php (or some another **global** file). Then just build path using that constant. Obviously, this is not a actual answer for asked functionality but rather alternative approach to the problem. IDE has functionality to copy path **relative** to the project root, but it will not work for your case, which is "path relative to the current file".

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but using PHP namespaces with autoloaders are going to save you a ton of time in the future. https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/tree/master/accepted Look at PSR-0

Comment: @LazyOne actually, I think "copy path relative to the project root" is  exactly what I'm after; how do I do that?

Comment: It's called **`Edit | Copy Reference`**. For file -- invoke from context menu of Project View or similar (e.g. Editor Tab context menu .. or Nav Bar context menu).

Answer (score 1):

Apache stores the path to the document root folder in an environmental variable which you can access from PHP like this:

```
$ROOT = getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT");
```

Then you can say:

```
require("$ROOT/lib/somefile.php");
```

If you are usign IIS see [this article in helicron.net](http://www.helicron.net/php-document-root/).

Answer (score 1):

If it is not an overkill, I would suggest to use an auto loader.
Here is a standalone one from symfony components: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/class_loader/introduction.html 
I am sure that Zend or other frameworks have the same ability.

It handles the location of files and may even remove your need to require files manually.

Reinventing the wheel is cumbersome for production, IMHO.